# Other special characters for newline?

Tags: php, string

I'm able to get rid of all `\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\r`, `\n`, `PHP_EOL`, and `\t` pieces from a string. I've also found (I think) most of the whitespace-related special characters: `&#9;`, `&#10;`, `&#13;`, `&emsp;`, `&ensp;`, and for kicks `&para;` and `&#182;` which should mean the same thing, but I was running out of things to try.

However, when I process the string, there's still a newline from time to time. There doesn't seem to be a trend. Is there a special character or something else missing from this list that would leave a newline in a `textarea`?

Newlines before and after the ones left are removed, and the script's thorough on the first round by ensuring it never breaks out of its loop until there aren't any changes. As a guarantee-test, I tried `str_replace` on all of the above and it didn't change anything.

When I copy and paste the string into a doc with hidden characters enabled, it displays a paragraph symbol in those places, but copying/pasting that character into the script as a replacement didn't work, either.

So, what's missing?

Edited to add `&#10;` and `&#13;`

Edit:
The problem with adding code is that it's spread out and based on an array that gets cycled through. The below is a straightforward bit that (Now) removes 'all' instances in a string. It looks like adding `&#10;` and `&#13;` fixes it in the 'replace all,' but didn't in my circumstance-driven script, so I'll have to figure that one out. At least I know what I was missing now. :)

```
$this->keys = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n", PHP_EOL);
str_ireplace($this->keys, "", $this->formatted);
str_ireplace(array("\t", "&#9;", "&emsp;", "&ensp;", "&para;", "&#182;", "&#10;", "&#13;"), "", $this->decodeHTML($this->formatted));
```

Comment: can you add the code you are using to sanitize the string please

Comment: `&para;` is the literal ¶ symbol, not a space or newline.

Comment: *"So, what's missing?"* **A: Code.** - To which @cmorrissey asked for, but alas; no code in the update. If the answer given doesn't solve it, then they're waiting just like everyone else to see which animal(s) we're dealing with here.

Comment: oh, you're "one of those" I see. Nice; well that was flagged.

Comment: @DrakeM. please do not be rude and do not call people names unless you wish for a trip to banned camp.

Comment: Next time, leave the guesswork out and post your code from the get go.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I explained what characters I was using and said I used str_replace. Not a complicated leap from that to the script. In fact, the script displays exactly what I described and what you could have imagined.

Comment: When you ask for help from strangers it's best to provide information instead of expecting them to make the correct assumptions.  Read the SO guidelines on writing good questions.

Comment: @shaunhusain Fine, fine. I got criticized on a separate question for providing too much detail and now I'm being grilled for leaving out the obvious. Guess I'm just destined to be ridiculed here. :P

Comment: Always good to include and try to create a minimal reproduction of the problem so people who have good advice don't have to learn the whole system it is a bit of a balancing act, not here to criticize really and code was here by the time I read it but hard to answer questions in a void.

Comment: @shaunhusain Eh, there's a reason I don't use SO anymore than I absolutely have to other than through search... it's not two isolated instances.

Comment: @JayBlanchard So it's perfectly fine to be overzealous but not fine to call 'em out on it? Got it.

Comment: You can call out over-zealousness @DrakeM. you just cannot call them names. Just remember that folks here are volunteers with lives just as busy as yours.

Comment: @JayBlanchard So recommend a way to call 'em out in a way that it doesn't say what their activity suggests of them?

Comment: To that I would say, "Discretion is the better part of valor." At this point you just need to let it go.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I did let it go. Merely asking for future reference, 'cause there're plenty on this site. :)

Answer (score 2):

This code is working for me:

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

Btw. `PHP_EOL` contains these characters: `\n`, `\n\r` and `\r\n`. So it is unnecessary to remove them separately. Bur `PHP_EOL` doesn't contain `\r`!

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: `\n` or `\v` would be better.

Comment: I wasn't sure about PHP_EOL, because I've read a dozen different places different pieces: "It's a cure-all, it shouldn't be used as a replacement," etc. So. Good to know that it's more like an array. :)

Answer (score 1):

`chr(10)` [linefeed] and `chr(13)` [carriage return] are not on your list.

And, of course, if you are outputting to html, `<br>` and `<br/>`.

Comment: Thanks for that, just tried it, they're still there. But at least that adds a couple more to the list. :)

Comment: Post your code for removing newlines please

Comment: why not simply go to the point where you are getting a new line and see what is being echoed there?

Comment: @DrakeM. Add the string to the question that causes the issue. Also show the code you are using.

Comment: The issue is with the replacement run apparently because those characters did work in the replace-all circumstance. Can't accept it yet, have to wait 24 hours apparently. And actually, thinking about it... I know why it replaces in one situation and not the other.

Comment: @tonygil I had considered <br>, but because it didn't show up in the textarea, I figured it wasn't that. Since when I put anything in the textarea that's remotely HTML-like, it doesn't parse it. Good suggestion though if circumstances were different.